# “SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input” in Wordpress checkout - how to debug?

Tags: plugins

Under the woocommerce_payment_complete hook I got my function which uses the wp_create_user function. When I want to make a new order then woocommerce shows me an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input", console shows "Unable to fix malformed JSON" and there are no new lines at debug.log

The one interesting part is that when I click "make an order" again (without refreshing) then I can make the order. When I refresh the page and try for the first time again then again the error shows.

Anyone know how can I debug that?

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this problem with our site. The mentioned syntax error happened because we made some changes to our .htaccess file and there were spaces in between the lines. I know it's a year late, but for the next person this might be helpful.